# Fixed background issue on ipad (iOS5)

Tags: ipad, html, ios5, css, webkit

Currently building a new blog and having issues with a fixed cover background on ipad - works fine on browsers but scrolls on iPad, tried a lot of things including creating a separate background div with position:fixed z-index:-1; which created the same effect.

I not to sure why this is happening as I thought position:fixed and background-attachment: fixed were meant to be sorted in iOS5?

You can view it here: http://reactionproductions.com/tumblr/

Answer (score 1):

After days looking for the solutions, here is: http://ryanfait.com/resources/fixed-positioning-in-internet-explorer/

And this is how works for me:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
}
html, body {

    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    overflow-y: scroll !important; 
}
#background_wrap {
    background: #000000 url(xxxxx.jpg); no-repeat center center fixed;
   -webkit-background-size: cover; 
   -moz-background-size: cover; 
   -o-background-size: cover; 
    background-size: cover; 
    background-position: center; 
   -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch !important;  
    z-index: 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}

#page {
   -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;

}
.box {
    position: fixed;
    left: 10px;
    top: 180px;
}
* html .box {
    position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to select in the CSS via

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1023px){
body {
    background: cover;/*etc*/
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%; 
    position: absolute; 
  }
}
```

and play around. you could also add

```
@media screen and landscape and (min-width: 1023px)
```

and with portrait so fetch well the ipad device.
hope it helps.

Comment: Have been experimenting with this before and only result I can get is for the background to cover the whole 100% of the content including scrolling (so stretched to like 4000px high). What's weird that my left panel (logo/description) is positioned as fixed too and that continues to scroll on iPad

Comment: you could try with: background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size:contain;. Also maybe use the safari -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;another solution i can think of is to create a div wuith header width, and other div with left menu width and height and a div with the content width and height and place inside the content and scroll it with scroll-y so the effect divs(header,leftmenu,content) will be as fixed...just throwing ideas, hope you find the solution,

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this solution? Put it in an onScroll event handler of the window:

```
if(navigator.platform == 'iPad' || navigator.platform == 'iPhone' || navigator.platform == 'iPod')
{
    //set background fixed with javascript
    var element = document.getElementById('background');
    element.style.webkitTransform = "translate3d(0, " + window.pageYOffset + "px, 0)";
};
```